# Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume

Tags: powershell

we are using powershell script for capturing the disk space & memory utilization related parameters for x number of servers and using the command `"Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume"` we are able to get the required output for most of the servers , however couple of servers are throwing the following two type of errors :

> 1. Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
> 2. Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

In the above error # 1, its being observed that the servers which are in DMZ/ not in Windows Domain are throwing this error, however ,

the error # 2 above is for set of servers which are in Non-DMZ and placed inside Windows Domain and still throwing the error.

The option of using the `"Get-WmiObject win32_service –credential mydomain\administrator"` is not helping as the server count is huge.

Seems, some workaround can be explored using the option of "Enter -PSSession"

Kindly help in above scenario at the earliest.

Comment: Haven't considered something like the following?

`$creds = Get-Credential mydomain\administrator
Get-WmiObject win32_service –credential $creds`

Comment: yes, its part of the script and the credentials are limited for the servers in Non-DMZ(one which are in domain)

Comment: Yeah, I get that, the line _"The option of using the "Get-WmiObject win32_service –credential mydomain\administrator" is not helping as the server count is huge."_ had me a bit confused however. This seems like two completely separate problems and would perhaps best be split into two different questions.

Comment: Use [`Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WmiObject`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/02/08/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/). The former uses WinRM whereas the latter uses DCOM. Requires PowerShell v3 or newer, though.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, only 2-3 srvrs got added by using the "Get-CimInstance". Tried with both hostname & ip addr. listing in the input file, Mostly I am getting messages as 1. "Get-CimInstance : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred".  2.Get-CimInstance : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. A DMTF resource URI was used to access a non-DMTF class. 
Try again using a non-DMTF resource URI. it seems the Servers which are not in domain are causing the problem.

Comment: Hosts that aren't in a (trusted) domain must be manually added to the trusted hosts list on the client side.